# SSRS export Excel sheet to prenamed Excel sheet that contains formulas based on SQL data

Tags: sql, excel, reporting-services

I want to export an SSRS report programmatically to a presaved Excel sheet pointing to a sheet that is prenamed so that the formulas on a pivot table in that Excel sheet automatically produce a result. The whole idea of doing it this way is to reduce the need for retyping formulas. Exporting it using the option that is available doesn't go to the extent I want it to.

I attempted to use SSRS expressions embedded into the report but every time I want to run an expression over the report data I have to retrieve the data from SQL all over again. It is very heavy on processing time.

I would almost prefer to run the expressions over the data that has been retrieved without having to run the report again and again every time I change a parameter or condition. I have not been able to come across away of running sum expressions when the data is retrieved. Anyone have any ideas on the best approach or some custom code that would allow me to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't do this out of the box.  I wrote an app that takes SQL Queries and drops the results into pre-determined locations but it was overkill. I now build Excel workbooks templates with a datamodel to hold the data which will fetch the data on demand when the user does a simple "refresh-all". In most cases, I don;' use Excel formulae either, I add new calculated measures directly in Power Query which are then available to pivot tables or whatever you need.

Comment: I've used SSIS VB script tasks to populate an Excel file using `Workbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(Row, Column) = CellValue` to populate cells.